# Iteratorを使って、リスト内に同じ要素があった場合、取り除く方法を教えてください

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで質問です

①入力してその数を入れたlistnumberの中に、同じ数が入っていたら、後の数を削除したいです。
以下のコードのように書きましたが、うまくいきません。どのように書けばいいでしょうか？

```
if(i==i){it.removes();}
```

② 「もし0が入っていたらそいつを削除する」というぷろぐらむを書きたくて、以下のコードを書いたところ、エラーが出たので、Iteratorを使いました。なぜ以下のようなfor文ではなく、Iteratorの方がいいのでしょうか？

```
for(listnumber==0){remove.listnumber[i]}
```

以下、全体のコードです。

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.List;

public class Main2{
  

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    ArrayList<Integer> listnumber = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    
    
    int number=sc.nextInt();
    listnumber.add(number);
    
    }
    System.out.println("nyuryoku End");

      //イテレータを使って、このように書くのがキレイ。
      
      
      while(it.hasNext()){
        int i = it.next();
        //もしリストの要素に0が含まれていたらそいつを消す
        if(i  == 0) {it.remove();}
        //もしリスト内に同じ数字が含まれていたらそいつを消す
        if(i==i){it.removes();}
    }
     System.out.println("登録データ数:" + listnumber.size());

    for(int n=0;n<listnumber.size();n++){

     System.out.println("listnumber"+listnumber.get(n));
    }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: そのままでは無いですが①の方はこちらに3種類ほど関連する処理の例が載っています。[How to Remove Duplicates from ArrayList in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-arraylist-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

> うまくいきません。どのように書けばいいでしょうか？

これは、自分の値と自分の値が同じなら。という常にtrueを返す条件で比較をしているからです。これを自分で書くとわりと面倒です。
そこで同じ値を含ませたくない。
特定の文字を含ませたくない。などのデータ整形に対する処理を手軽に書ける
Stream API使うと楽に表現できますが、それではだめですか？

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> listnumber = sc.tokens().filter(
            o-> o!=null && !o.equals("0")) //Nullと0を除去
            .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))//String -> Integer 変換
            .distinct()//重複データの削除
            .collect(Collectors.toList());//Stream->List変換
```